# Scala - Java interop: can Scala emit enums in bytecode for Java to consume?

Tags: java, scala, enums, bytecode, interop

I have a project that is mixed Java/Scala, it is Java GUI code that makes use of a Scala library. Is there a way to write Scala code such that it will emit Java enums on compile time? The approaches I tried so far (sealed case classes, extend Enumeration) seem to generate normal classes which makes working with them from Java much hairier than straight up enums.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why can't you write your `enum` class *in Java*? Mixed-source (i.e. Java + Scala) projects are perfectly feasible...

Comment: Indeed, that was also my conclusion, I will accept this answer. Maven support for mixed projects is still very flaky though.

Comment: I continue to write my enums in Java for exactly this reason.

Answer (score 0):

Scala only supports Java 1.4 features at this point.

Java Enums were introduced in Java 1.5.

Comment: Generics are implemented with type erasure, after compilation there are no generics anymore. But Scala supports annotations and those are retained when compiling to bytecode and that is most definitely a Java 1.5 feature.

Comment: Generics in java is implemented via type erasure as well

Comment: What Boris meant is that Scala only support JVM 1.4 features. Language features that do no exist on the bytecode are irrelevant. Except, of course, interface-wise. :-)

Comment: @Daniel, My understanding is that JVM bytecode hasn't changed since 1.0. So the only differences between 1.4 and 1.5 are language features.

Comment: The class file format was extended to accommodate at least enums and annotations, but it's possible they managed it in a backwards compatible way. JSR 202 should have the details ( http://www.jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=202 )